# Duplicate a div using clone in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my web application, I've a select box and two text boxes grouped inside  a div. The value in 2 textboxes will be filled based on the select box selection using ajax. Now my task is to duplicate this whole div when a button is clicked. I've accomplished this by using jquery clone method. its working fine. But when I try to select an option in duplicated div, the selection happens on the parent div itself. Didn't know where am going wrong. Can anyone please help me. Also I need to work the ajax call in the select box in duplicated div's also.
Here is my code I've done so far.

view:

```
    <div class="row" id="addparts">
<div class="form-group"  >
<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Job Description<span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span></h3>

<select name="complainttype[]" id="country_list2" class="form-control" onChange="getjobdata(this.value)">
<option selected select disabled>Select</option>
<?php
foreach($complaints as $com)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $com->id;?>"><?php echo $com->type;?></option>
<?php
}

?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Remarks<span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span></h3>
<input type="text" name="remarks[]" id="remarks" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Work Hours<span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span></h3>
<input type="text" name="work_hours[]" id="work_hours" class="form-control">
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {       

var item = $("#addparts");
var before = $('#div_button');
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
var clone = item.clone(true);
clone.attr('id', '');
clone.attr('class', 'duplicate');
before.before(clone);
});
});
```

//ajax function to fill the textboxes

```
function getjobdata(val)
{
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>index.php/test/ajaxgetjobdata",
data: {id: val},
cache:false,
success: function(data) {
//alert(data);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var remarks=obj.remarks;
var work_hours=obj.work_hrs;
//var model=obj.model;
document.getElementById("remarks").value = remarks;
document.getElementById("work_hours").value = work_hours;
},
error: function() {
alert("error");
}

});
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,
I have changed this line `var item = $("#addparts");` to `var item = $("#country_list2");`
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
var item = $("#country_list2");
var before = $('#div_button');
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
    alert("test");
var clone = item.clone(true);
clone.attr('id', '');
clone.attr('class', 'duplicate');
before.before(clone);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: But I need to duplictae the whole div, means the duplicated div should contain select box and both textboxes. If I do like you said, it'll only replicate the select box.

Comment: That's my mistake. Forgot to put that addparts div. Check my edit

Comment: your clones select dropdown has same id "country_list2" you need to change this dynamically

Comment: I tried changing the dropdown's id but didn't work.. Also I'm a noob in jquery/javascript.